# How to plot transformed time series ETS forecast in original units in R?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

Is there an easy way to plot transformed time series ETS forecasts (from the `forecast` package in `R`) in their original units?

```
library(forecast)
AP   <- AirPassengers
fit1 <- ets(log(AP), model="AAA")
fit2 <- ets(BoxCox(AP, BoxCox.lambda(AP)), model="AAA")
plot(forecast(fit1)) # Log Transformed
plot(forecast(fit2)) # Box-Cox Transformed
```

How can I plot the final two lines in the original units of `AP`?  Look at `plot(AP)`

Likewise, is there an easy way to "back-transform" the confidence intervals from `forecast(fit1)` and `forecast(fit2)`?

*Note: Not sure if this should exist on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) instead of SO?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading the help files is always a good idea. You will find there that `ets` has a `lambda` argument that does what you want.

```
library(forecast)
AP   <- AirPassengers
fit1 <- ets(AP, model="AAA", lambda=0)
fit2 <- ets(AP, model="AAA", lambda = BoxCox.lambda(AP))
plot(forecast(fit1)) 
plot(forecast(fit2))
```

Comment: Thanks @RobHyndman - not sure I would have inferred that as quickly from reading the help file. And thank you for an **awesome** (!) [package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forecast/index.html) and [book](https://www.otexts.org/fpp)